# JSON Schema required attributes

Tags: json, rest, schema, jsonschema

i've tried to find a similar answer but couldn't, so here it goes:

When defining the schema for a json document, if we define an attribute as required, is this requirement for input data, or is it for input and output?
Example:
let's say we have a property called Id. This Id always exists for the resource, but this Id is generated by the server. If i want to publish my schema for public consumption, and i allow someone to create instances of this resource, should the Id be defined as required or not? Are the required properties only those that the consumers of the API MUST send to create the resource, or are all the properties that the resource always have, including server generated  properties?

Comment: Also, should i define in the schema only those properties the API consumers can send (even if optional) or should i define also those properties that are server generated (like dateCreated, dateUpdated, etc)?

Comment: Are you implying that the Id property is never used by the consumer in any of your use cases and that it's an artifact of your server?

Comment: The Id is used as a read-only property. It's used to access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate that the "id" key is there then you should make it required. What you could do is have two different schemas: one to validate the schema from the user (sans "id") and one to validate the api call one which would include the "id" key